# Condiciones en eloquent de laravel

Tags: laravel

estoy haciendo un filtrador de productos pero no se como hacer para ir añadiendo las condiciones a la consulta, he probado de la siguiente manera, pero como es normal me obliga a marca una opción de cada una.

```
$productos = Product::with('variaciones')
   ->join('categories', 'products.categoria', '=', 'categories.id')
   ->join('subcategories', 'products.subcategoria', '=', 'subcategories.id')
   ->join('marcas', 'products.proveedor', '=', 'marcas.id')
   ->select('products.*', 'categories.name as nameCategoria', 'subcategories.name as nameSubcategoria', 'marcas.empresa as proveedor')
   ->whereIn('products.categoria', $data["categoria"])
   ->whereIn('products.subcategoria', $data["subcategoria"])
   ->latest('id')
   ->paginate(6);
```

Alguna idea??

Comment: Hola @BetaM si correcto, luego iran más pero queria probar así

Comment: De este modo @BetaM me sigue pidiendo marcar las dos opciones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes separarlos en consultas independientes, pero todo debe complirse, cada condiocional, y lo `or` no podrias hacerlo, pero almenos no estas obligado a seleccionar todo

```
$productos = Product::with('variaciones')
   ->join('categories', 'products.categoria', '=', 'categories.id')
   ->join('subcategories', 'products.subcategoria', '=', 'subcategories.id')
   ->join('marcas', 'products.proveedor', '=', 'marcas.id')
   ->select('products.*', 'categories.name as nameCategoria', 'subcategories.name as nameSubcategoria', 'marcas.empresa as proveedor');

//verificamos que exista y contenga almenos 1 dato
if(isset($data["categoria"]) && count($data["categoria"])){
   $productos = $productos->whereIn('products.categoria', $data["categoria"])
}

//verificamos que exista y contenga almenos 1 dato
if(isset($data["subcategoria"]) && count($data["subcategoria"])){
   $productos = $productos->whereIn('products.subcategoria', $data["subcategoria"])
}

//mas filtros

//solo como ejemplo, en caso de obtener el ultimo
if($last){
   $productos = $productos->latest('id')
}else{
   //o devolver la lista
   $productos = $productos->paginate(6);
}
```

Comment: Hola y gracias por tu respuesta, funciona perfectamante. Pero no me pagina los resultados, donde hay que poner en este caso el `{{ $productos->render() }}`

Comment: `productos` debe ser una `lista (Array) mayor al paginate` si no lo es, no habrá paginacion, mejor dicho no hay necesidad de mostrar, en este caso de `6` cuando tengas `>6` recien se mostrará `{{productos->links()}}`

Comment: Pero realmente hay 8 productos cuando marco todas las categorías? en este caso deberia de mostrarlo no?

Comment: y otra coasa @manrrique meneses yaranga puedo hacer que se ejecute este ajax al cargar la página, o como no hay click no se puede?

Comment: @Miguel si se puede pero tienes que haces muchas cosas con `javascrit` desde prevenir `submit -> form` hasta `href -> a`, y le cargas los mismos datos, el `paginate` ya genera el `link` y página a mostrar, `$request->ajax()` validas que es ajax, y devulves otra vista parcial, en lugar de todo

Comment: Hola @manrrique meneses yaranga . Soy algo novato en programación y sobre todo si se trata de JavaScript!. No se como avanzar está parte ya que no se que construir. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Considero que a partir de tu `$request` puedes filtrar en un condicional y dependiendo si este contiene uno u otro valor entonces construir la consulta para solamente tener un `whereIn` en ella, en función de determinar si un valor esta presente o no

```
    if ($request->has('categoria')) {
        /*
            Si en el request viene el valor de categoria 
        */
    } else {
        /*
            Si en el request viene el valor de subcategoria
        */
   }
```

De este modo:

- En el `if` compones la consulta con un solo `whereIn` para filtrar por categoría
- En el `else` compones la consulta para filtrar por el valor contrario al punto anterior

**Referencia**

- Aqui puedes leer mas sobre [si un valor esta o no presente en el $request](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, utilize la del compañero y funciona. Voy a probar está también. Una cosa te respondi en mi otra pregunta que me respondiste anoche, por si puedes verla